# \floatstyle{boxed} paragraph style

Tags: floats, paragraphs, line-spacing

I'm using `\floatstyle{boxed}` for the first time.

I want numbered, boxed floats with the same paragraph style as my main document. 
The boxing and numbering works fine, 
but the line-spacing inside the box is single-spaced (not my document default) 
and new  paragraphs are not indented and not preceeded by a blank line. 
This makes my boxes messy to read. Why?

I'm doing this:

```
    %preamble
    \usepackage{float}  % enables user to define custom floats
    \floatstyle{boxed}  % affects the next call to \newfloat (and all subsequent ones until \floatstyle is called again)
    \newfloat{BoxFloat}{tbh}{bx}[chapter]
    \floatname{BoxFloat}{Box}   % set prefix for captions on instances of BoxFloat to 'Box'
    %body of document
    \begin{BoxFloat}
    \label{BoxFloat:subsumption}
    \caption{Clarke's subsumption problem}
    My first paragraph.

    My second paragraph.
    \end{BoxFloat}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which document class do you use? You mention that your default settings include not single spacing and additional vertical space between paragraphs; this is not the default in standard classes, so we might need to see the settings of your class.